# Show hidden fields on a html questionnaire form

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a questionnaire, which allows users to answer YES or NO to each question. if NO is clicked, field is hidden. But if YES is clicked, I want to show hidden field which has further instructions for each question.

The following code works for the first question, but not for subsequent question.

How can I amend the script to work for all questions on the questionnaire.

```js
function showhideInfo()
    {
    if (document.getElementById('inlineRadio1').checked) {
         document.getElementById('reqdfield').style.display = 'block';
         }
         else document.getElementById('reqdfield').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
          <b><label class = "label">Have you attended this course before</label></b>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="YES" onclick="showhideInfo()">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">YES</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="NO" onclick="showhideInfo()">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">NO</label>
            </div>
          <div class="regdInfo" id="reqdfield" style="display:none">
            You will need to provide details of previous course attended.
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ofc it's gonna work on 1 question only becuz you are calling the element by id of your 1st question only `inlineRadio1` and changing the element of a single hidden element which has the id `reqdfield` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Ids are (supposed to be) unique on a web page. In particular `getElementById` will return a single element only, even if there were multiple elements having the same ID in the document.

Use a selector based on the class instead. Eg:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.reqdInfo').forEach ( pe => { pe.style.display = 'none'; /* or 'block' */ });
```